# Can't access resources through JSAPI

Tags: arcgis-server, csv, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Simply I want to upload a tiny csv file to a buffer Geoprocessing service published through ArcGIS Server 10.4.1. The problem ,however, is that I can't access any file in my server or an external server no matter what method that I use. I have tried uploading the file directly to the GP tool -I can upload it from the service directory- , using request function and even defining csvURL that is actually working in an example published by ESRI, sometimes even those examples when I download their sources everything works fine except the layers csv,kml,... I can't call them.
I don't know what is blocking my requests is it the firewall or the proxy?
I am still new to this field.